# Where to find the iHasApp framework?

Tags: objective-c

my app got rejected 2 times due to this issue:

"Specifically, we found that this app checks for all apps installed on this device by scanning all known URL schemes using a service called iHasApp"

My code doesn't have the iHasApp framework, i tried to search for it but i can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be using iHasApp and now a days apple is rejecting this kind of  app. iHasApp misuses "canOpenURL:".

Comment: how can i check it? i did check all .h and .m files, there are not iHasApp header file, there is no framework on my source code. :(

Comment: look for canOpenURL calls